# Custom user model object not created after allauth signup

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth, django-custom-user

I'm trying to create a custom user object (Author model) right after a new user signs up using [allauth's signal](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html), the signup works fine and the User is created but the object (Author) is not being created.

**This is my Author (custom user) model:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

**This is what I have in my view:**

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def after_user_signed_up(request, user):
    author = Author.objects.create(user=user)
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Should I be setting the custom user differently to make this work? I'll be adding more fields to the Author model later on and I saw that doing a one-to-one relation should be the way to go, but not sure why this isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at `post_save` signals in django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer - I needed to, either:

1. move the function into my model.py module, or
2. keep function in my view or in a signals.py module, but manually add that module to my apps.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NameOfAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'NameOfApp'

    def ready(self):
        import NameOfApp.signals
```